# Using Jquery, how to change color with if/else condition

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, if-statement

In fact, I have 2 boxes, id named box1 and box2.

I am using J-query.

My design:

Click box1 => check box2 background color, if it is black, change it white, else change black.

My hard code:

```
<body>
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
</body>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#box1").click(function(){
        if ($('#box2').css({backgroundColor: 'white'})) {
            $('#box2').css({backgroundColor: 'black'});
        } else {
            $('#box2').css({backgroundColor: 'white'});
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you'll see in the snippet here, jQuery reports back the RGB value of the cell for it's background color. It's much easier to use classes for this kind of thing. in this case, you can just use [toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Also, for the record, your IF statement was malformed:

```
if ($('#box2').css({backgroundColor: 'white'})) {
```

should be

```
if ($('#box2').css('background-color') ==  'white') {
```

... but it would fail because it's actually `rgb(255, 255, 255)`, not `white`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#box1").click(function() {
    console.log('The background color of box 2 is: ', $('#box2').css('background-color'))
    $("#box2").toggleClass('black');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: white;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
```